# Adding new .aspx item in our project through our program?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I have a Tree View in my application. If i add a node(Parent or Child) then the node should be add and corresponding .aspx page should also be added to our project... For example

My tree contains 'Programming' as parent Node and 'c','c++','C#'.. as child node. And one textbox to add more nodes. If i insert 'java' and click add button then that (java) should be added as child node and 'java.aspx' page should be added in our project.

Can we do this??

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, there are other webbased applications which allow you to add a aspx/ascx to your file system (Sitecore for instance) so you can.
I guess you can do this with a StreamWriter: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287548(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: it creating .aspx file but its not creating .aspx.cs  and .aspx.designer.cs pages for that page. And its saving in project folder but its not displaying in 'service explorer' in visual studio